Funcion google apps script contar celdas de un determinado color en un rango
Quiero conseguir una función que cuente el número de celdas de un rango de celdas de un determinado color.
Tengo el siguiente código:
    function contarCeldasColor(rango,colorHex) {
  // Convierte el rango en un objeto de rango
  const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  rangoCeldas = hoja.getRange(rango);
  //const rangoCeldas = hoja.getRange("N7:N");
  //const valores = rango.getValues();
  
  // Convierte el código de color hexadecimal a minúsculas (por consistencia)
  //const colorTarget = colorHex.toLowerCase();
  let contador = 0;

  // Recorre cada celda del rango y cuenta las que coinciden con el color especificado
  for (let i = 1; i <= rangoCeldas.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= rangoCeldas.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      const colorCelda = rangoCeldas.getCell(i, j).getBackground();
      if (colorCelda.toLowerCase() === colorHex) {
        contador++;
      }
    }
  }

  return contador;
}

Si intento poner el rango como argumento de la función me da error, en cambio cuando lo paso dentro del script cuenta correctamente. He probado con comillas y sin en el rango.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Hola. El área de abajo es para respuestas. Si quieres aclarar algo de la pregunta debes pulsar en [edit] y agregar debajo de la pregunta las cosas nuevas que vayan apareciendo. Dicho eso, no queda claro el contexto en el que quieres aplicar esto. En la imagen se ve que lo quieres aplicar como si fuera una fórmula ¿? Quizá si dieras más información sobre el contexto podríamos orientarte para realizar esto de la mejor manera. ¿Por qué intentas lanzarlo manualmente, como si fuera una fórmula? En cuanto al tipo de rango, ¿por qué quieres lanzarlo en un rango que no tendría ninguna limitación?

Revisa la respuesta, que acabo de editar. El código funciona llamando a la función así: contarCeldasColor("N7:N","#f9cb9c") Pero la llamada se hace desde Apps Script. Quizá el problema es que no tengas claro desde dónde debe llamarse la función ¿?

En el código de la pregunta ni siquiera aparece la forma en que estás llamando a la función, que es el supuesto error. Ahí se vería qué rango de celdas estás pasando y qué código de color. Un elemento sospechoso es este tipo de rango que aparece comentado en tu código: "N7:N". ¿Qué rango se supone que querrías alcanzar ahí? Revisa la documentación, para comprender los formatos que puedes usar para alcanzar rangos.
Por otra parte, convendría que aclares el contexto desde el cual quieres llamar a esta función.
Supongamos una hoja con algo como esto en la columna N:

Si definimos la función así:
function contarCeldasColor(rango,colorHex) {
  // Convierte el rango en un objeto de rango
  const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  rangoCeldas = hoja.getRange(rango);
  let contador = 0;
  // Recorre cada celda del rango y cuenta las que coinciden con el color especificado
  for (let i = 1; i <= rangoCeldas.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= rangoCeldas.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      let colorCelda = rangoCeldas.getCell(i, j).getBackground();
      if (colorCelda.toLowerCase() === colorHex) {
        Logger.log(`colorCelda: ${colorCelda} colorHex: ${colorHex}`)
        contador++;
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(`contador: ${contador}`)
  return contador;
}

Y la llamamos así:
contarCeldasColor("N7:N","#f9cb9c")

El código funciona de la manera esperada.
Los registros de salida muestran esto:
Información colorCelda: #f9cb9c colorHex: #f9cb9c
Información colorCelda: #f9cb9c colorHex: #f9cb9c
Información colorCelda: #f9cb9c colorHex: #f9cb9c
Información colorCelda: #f9cb9c colorHex: #f9cb9c
Información contador: 4

Encontró cuatro celdas con color #f9cb9c a partir de la celda N7.

Con el rango "N7:N" indico todas las celdas por debajo de la celda N7, y en la misma columna, lo he utilizado en muchas ocasiones sin problemas.
He puesto el código que me dices y me sigue dando error. Dejo una imagen.
Muchas gracias de nuevo por la ayuda.

Llamo a la función desde la barra de fórmulas de la hoja, como cualquier otra función, y el código lo tengo en Apps Script.
Dejo enlace [a hoja][2]
[2]:
Gracias.
Solucionado!!!  He de separar los argumentos con punto y coma en lugar de una coma....
Gracias!
